# Line 24: error: incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        
        if(strs.length==0)
           return new ArrayList<>();
           
        Map<String,List<String>> anagrams=new HashMap<>();
        String anagram_key;
        
        for(String s:strs){
            char[] arr=s.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            anagram_key=String.valueOf(arr);

            if(!anagrams.containsKey(anagram_key))
                anagrams.put(anagram_key,new ArrayList<>());

            anagrams.get(anagram_key).add(s);
        }
        
        List<String> resList=new ArrayList<>();

        for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> _itr:anagrams.entrySet()){
            resList.add(_itr.get());
        }

        return resList;
    }
}
```

Was Expecting List Of String Array.
Running fine on my Intellij Idea IDE but not on leet code

The Error shown on leetcode is as follows:
Please Review + Any Effective Source To Learn More About Errors.

```
Line 24: error: incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to String
    resList.add(_itr.getValue());
                             ^
Line 27: error: incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to List<List<String>>
return resList;
       ^
2 errors
```

Comment: `resList` has been declared as `List<String> resList=new ArrayList<>()` and you are returning `resList` i.e. the return type should be `List<String>`. You have declared the return type wrongly as `Map<String,List<String>>`.

Comment: Alternatively, the type of `resList` should be declared as `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce exactly. Instead I get *Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Entry'*.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of your method? Something with anagrams, but more exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You last code section should look something like this:

```java
List<List<String>> resList=new ArrayList<>();

for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> _itr:anagrams.entrySet()){
    resList.add(_itr.getValue());
}

return resList;
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. A simpler (or at least shorter) version of the same would be `return new ArrayList<>(anagrams.values());`.